# Use shall for first person instead of'will'

Tags: grammar

My teacher said, "nowadays we don't use 'shall' instead of 'will'",  but I read and hear that!
Can you tell me about this contradiction?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your first question on ELL. I've made a few edits to clarify the question and improve the English. You're welcome to keep the edits or reject them. Just so you're aware, the more you can say in your question about what you're asking the better received your question will be. I would suggest you give examples of where you've read and heard the usage you're asking about, and explain your own thoughts about why your experience might be different from what your teacher said.

Answer (score 3):

Some people do, some don't.

In my (English English) dialect, I don't usually use either in affirmative statements ("I'll go"), but I use "will" or "shall" in negative ones ("I won't/shan't go"); but I always use "shall" in a question when I am asking for permission or confirmation: "Shall I go?" "Shall I open the window?"

But many speakers of Scottish English do not use "shall" even in questions, and say "Will I go?", which sounds odd to me.

My impression is that American English uses "shall" less than English English, but I'm not sure.

[Note: I'm using "English English" rather than "British English", because in the respect the Scottish English is different].

Comment: Americans only use "shall" after having heard British-influenced cultures speak.  I don't remember it even being part of my English language classes growing up (I'm sure it was mentioned, but it obviously didn't form a memory).  However, I agree completely with your statement about questions - that's by far and away the most common place for me to hear it in the western U.S.

Comment: I'm not sure that *shan't* is still a word in American English. But some of us still use *shall* in first person questions, and the ones who don't use *should* or something similar. *Will I close the window?* in a question sounds really wrong to me. (*Will I go to jail?* is fine, but *will* in first person questions is only for things I/we have no control over.)

Comment: As an _American_ I typically only use "shall" sarcastically. I rarely (if ever) hear it used seriously in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it is disappearing. It is mostly dead in American English. In England, I believe it has connotations of class. It sounds like something an aristocrat from the past century would say. Although you still hear it here and there, in some situations. As someone who is learning English as a foreign language, there is absolutely no need to learn anything about it, besides that it is a thing. After living three years in London, I am pretty sure I have only heard it in a mocking manner.

Anyway, this is an extract from Practical English Language, by Michael Swan. It is the only mention in the whole 700 pages book about a use of shall in which it is not just some fancy old-fashioned synonym of will.

> Questions with shall I/we are used (in both British and American English) to ask for instructions or decisions, to offer services, and to make suggestions. In American English, this is rather formal. Will is not used in this way.
> *Shall I open a window?* (not *Will I open a window?)
> Shall I carry your bag?
>
> What time shall we come and see you?
>
> What on earth shall we do?
>
> Shall we go out for a meal? Let's go and see Lucy, shall we?*